# Preserving entire JPA entity on each change

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, orm, audit

I'm working on an application with a Hibernate backend. One of the things I'd like it to be able to do is to have asynchronous event handlers fire on  JPA entity object updates. The tricky part is that once a JPA entity is updated, there is no longer any persistent reference to the original object.

The end goal is to store the the original *and* the updated entity in such a way that the asynchronous component can see them both *in their entirety*. I can think of a couple possible ways to get around this, but they all strike me as complex.

- Serialize the original object, store it in the database somewhere, and refer to it asynchronously
- Serialize the updated object, send it as a JMS message, and update the database asynchronously
- Create a separate auditing object to track changes and replay them

Is there a simpler pattern for this kind of thing out there? Or is this just something I should embrace complexity on?

Comment: Not sure if you've already tried JPA PreUpdate and PostUpdate callbacks - just save the state of your object in each. 
Also, it seems to me that something like Hibernate Envers might be handy, in this case you have a journal with every object change http://docs.jboss.org/envers/docs/

Comment: I'm familiar with those callbacks, but how do you "save the state"? Somewhere, you have to persist the entire contents of the pre-updated entity (relationships and all) alongside the current entity. That's the part for which I'm hoping there's a common pattern or maybe a tool.

Comment: For our system, we're using your first idea: "Serialize the original object, store it in the database somewhere..." Say we have a PERSON_NAME table. When a person's name changes, we "deactivate" their name in the table using a flag and add the new name record. So we're storing historical objects in the same table as active objects and using a flag to differentiate them. It works all right. I'm not aware of a simpler pattern, but I'm inexperienced. Personally I'm going to have a closer look at Hibernate Envers -- thanks, @sap1ens.

Comment: @sap1ens I gave Hibernate Envers a shot, and it's pretty great so far. If you add that as an answer, I'll accept it!

Comment: Cool, just did it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me that Hibernate Envers might be handy, in this case you have a journal with every object change http://docs.jboss.org/envers/docs/

Answer (score 1):

Audit4j will help to persist your objects asynchronously. But it won't provide in-built support for JPA object changes. But there might be a way to implement with a workaround.